# Given an array find the number of sub arrays with m odd numbers?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

Sample Input: 
`1 2 3 4 5` (array elements)
`m = 1` (Odd numbers)
Sample output:
`8`.
The subarrays are [`[1]`, `[1,2]`, `[2,3]`, `[2,3,4]`, `[3]`, `[3,4]`, `[4,5]`, `[5]` ]

Here is my implementation.In the worst case, it would take O(n+n^2).Are there any ways to optimize this code?

```
int main() {
    int n, *a, count1=0, m, *dp;
    cin>>n;
    a = new int[n];
    dp =new int[n];

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        cin >> a[i];
    }

    cin >> m;

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        if(a[i]%2==1) {
            count1++;
        }

        dp[i] =count1;
    }

    int prev;
    long count=0;

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        prev= i==0 ? 0:dp[i-1];
        for(int j=i; j<n; j++) {
            if((dp[j] - prev) == m){
                count++;
            }

            if(dp[j] - prev > m){
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<count;
}
```

Comment: Just as a point of interest, big-O notation tends to only use the most significant term, so your algorithm would be O(n^2).

Answer (score 7):

This can be solved in `O(n)`.  First generate an array of the lengths of the gaps between odd numbers, counting both ends as implicit odd numbers.  In this case that array is `g = [0,1,1,0]`.  Then we sum `(g[i]+1)*(g[i+m]+1)` because that represents how many subarrays start at or just before the `i`'th odd, and end at or just after the `i+m`'th odd.

In this case we get `1*2 + 2*2 + 2*1 = 8`.

**Alternate explanation**
Think about the list of wanted subarrays.  Each one starts somewhere, includes `m` odd numbers, then ends somewhere else.  Let us divide them into groups based on which string of odd numbers they include.  Each group contains the `i`th odd number for some `i`, and ends at the `i+m-1`'th odd number.  The starting points are at every even number between the `i-1`th and `i`th odd numbers, and the `i`th odd number itself.  That's the size of the gap before the `i`th odd number + 1.  Or `g(i)+1` in my calculation.  Similarly the ending points are at the `i+m-1`th odd number, or at all the evens between that and the `i+m`th odd number.  That's 1 more the size of the gap between the `i+m-1`th and `i+m`th odd numbers.  Which is `g(i+m)+1` in my calculation.  The number in that group is therefore the number of starting points times the number of ending points.  Which is `(g(i)+1)*(g(i+m)+1)`.  Add that over all starting points `i` and we have our answer.

There is one important detail that I glossed over.  Which is that I am assuming that odd numbers are included, so `0 < m`.  If `m = 0` then the calculation changes completely.  The answer then turns out to be `1 + sum(g(i)*(g(i)-1)/2)`.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail please ?

Comment: @AkshayMathur This isn't a case of more explanation.  But rather alternate explanations until one clicks where the others didn't.  I'll add a second one.

Comment: https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/103416/contiguous-subarray    Read this for more clarity.

Comment: How do you get `g[i+m]` when `i` is indexing the last number in `g`?  `g[i+m]` would be a nonexistent element.  Are you wrapping around?

Comment: @ginna Where did you get the idea that `i` is indexing the last number in `g` from?  I am simply using `i` as an index variable.  It starts at 0 and goes until `i+m` reaches the end of the array.  No wrapping required.

Comment: Ah ok -- I thought the `i` was traversing the entire array, but sounds like it stops before the end

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get O(n log n). A simple improvement for your code is that in your inner loop (on j), instead of going one by one and counting you do a binary search on the interval [i, n] to find the first position that results in m odd numbers, and the first position that results in m+1 odd numbers; then subtract them.

However, to do this you need to have a sum[] array in which the ith position shows the number of odd numbers in interval [0, i]. This can be precomputed in O(n) with one for loop.

Now you use it like this in your binary search:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    int lo = i;
    int hi = n;

    while(lo < hi){
        int mid = (lo + hi)/2;
        int count = sum[mid];
        if(i > 0) count -= sum[i - 1];

        //count shows number of odd in the interval [i, mid]
        if(mid >= m){
            hi = mid;
        } 
        else{
            lo = mid + 1;
        }
    }

    int first_with_m = lo;

    //do another binary search to find first_with_m_plus_one

    answer += first_with_m_plus_one - first_with_m;
}
```